# Snake stops to move when key not pressed

Tags: c++

So my code is fine, I make the snake "wiggle" but it stops when I stop to press one key, so I wonder how I can make it so it moves always in the last direction without pressing a key ?

I know my code is kinda complicated but its only my first game so please be indulgent (forgiving). :)
I tried to put it in the loops but either it crashes or it stops to make the snake wiggle :(

I am new to game programming so it is strange for me to think in a loop based manner.

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#include <deque>

enum Direction { Up, Down, Right, Left};
int direction = Down;

class Block
{
    private:
    int ax, ay;

    public:
    Block(int, int);
    int getX();
    int getY();

};


class Snake
{
    private:
    std::deque<Block> asnake;
    int adirection;

    public:
    void Move(int);
    void grow();
    void shrink();
    std::deque<Block> getBlocks();
    int getX();
    int getY();
    Snake();
    void setdirection();
};

int main()
{
    sf::Event event;
    Snake snake;
    snake.setdirection();
    snake.grow();
    snake.grow();
    snake.grow();

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500,500), "SFML Snake");
    window.setFramerateLimit(30);
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:

                epicMusic.stop();
                window.close();
                break;

                default:

                break;
            }

        }

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
        {
                direction = Left;
                snake.Move(direction);
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
                direction = Right;
                snake.Move(direction);
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
        {
                direction = Down;
                snake.Move(direction);
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        {
                direction = Up;
                snake.Move(direction);
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Red);


        for(unsigned int i = 1; i < (snake.getBlocks()).size(); i++)
        {
            float x = (snake.getBlocks())[i].getX();
            float y = (snake.getBlocks())[i].getY();

            sf::RectangleShape block(sf::Vector2f(20,20));
            block.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
            block.setPosition(x, y);

            window.draw(block);
        }
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}

Block::Block(int x, int y)
{
    ax = x;
    ay = y;
}

int Block::getX()
{
    return ax;
}

int Block::getY()
{
    return ay;
}

void Snake::Move(int NewDirection)
{
    shrink();
    if(NewDirection == Up)
    {

        if(adirection != Down)
        {
            asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX(), asnake.front().getY() - 22));
            adirection = Up;
        }
        else
        {
            asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX(), asnake.front().getY() + 22));
        }
    }
    else if(NewDirection == Right)
    {
        if(adirection != Left)
        {
            asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX() + 25, asnake.front().getY()));
            adirection = Right;
        }
        else
        {
            asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX() - 25, asnake.front().getY()));
        }
    }
    else if(NewDirection == Down)
    {
            if(adirection != Up)
            {
                asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX(), asnake.front().getY() + 22));
                adirection = Down;
            }
            else
            {
                asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX(), asnake.front().getY() - 22));
            }

    }
    else if(NewDirection == Left)
    {
        if(adirection != Right)
        {
            asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX() - 25, asnake.front().getY()));
            adirection = Left;
        }
        else
        {
            asnake.push_front(Block(asnake.front().getX() + 25, asnake.front().getY()));
        }
    }

}

void Snake::grow()
{
    asnake.push_back(Block(asnake.back().getX(), asnake.back().getY()));
}
void Snake::shrink()
{
    asnake.pop_back();
}

std::deque<Block> Snake::getBlocks()
{
    return asnake;
}
int Snake::getX()
{
    return asnake.front().getX();
}

int Snake::getY()
{
    return asnake.front().getY();
}

Snake::Snake()
{
    asnake.push_front(Block(25,0));
    asnake.push_front(Block(50,0));
    asnake.push_front(Block(75,0));
}

void Snake::setdirection()
{
    adirection = Up;
}
```

Comment: You'll either need to learn multithreading (one thread to handle control events and the other to handle snake movement) so the controls and movement can run independently, OR you can run the movement in a loop and check for a key press that would update the direction on each loop cycle. Option 1 is a little more complicated, but you'll learn all sorts of good stuff.

Comment: Actually multithreading has nothing to do with this. The game is already running in a loop, he just needs to move `snake.Move(direction)` outside the if statements.

Comment: @user2687718 btw did you know there is SFML book? 
SFML Game Development

Comment: please precise clearly outside of which if and inside of which loop I should put the Move() because this can be confusing :)

Comment: if I put it outside the if(key presed) and in the while(window.isOpen()) it doesn't display the snake.

Comment: I MADE IT WORK!! puting it in window.isOpen right before the poll event made it work. IM SO CLEVER :D

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of "timer" that moves the snake in the same direction it is already pointing if there is no key pressed.

It looks like there is no timer event as such in SFML, but there is a way to measure time. 
http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-time.php

Also, you are "repeating yourself":

```
            snake.Move(direction);
```

is repeated four times. You just need to set the direction based on the key pressed, and if a key is pressed OR a certain amount of time has passed, perform a "snake.Move".

Comment: also putting the move outside of the if make the snake disappear

Comment: If the snake disappears, then you are doing something wrong for example running it straight off the screen because you have no timing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
snake.Move(direction);   // move the snake automatically (regardless of key presses)

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))     
      direction = Left;           // only change the direction when a key is pressed

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
      direction = Right;

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
      direction = Down;

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
      direction = Up;
```

Comment: by the way you didn't understand, I do not need a is_moving variable because I WANT THE SNAKE TO BE MOVING ALL THE TIME. :)

Comment: thanks a lot, figured the snake wouldn't disappear all at once if I put the move BEFORE the if, but now it doesn't move and disappear one element by one element and if I put one grow() after that, it doesn't move... don't answer why... seems like the only way to make it move without making it disappear is putting it in the if...

Comment: @user2687718 Well, what do you expect? Every time you call `Move`, the first line in your `Move` method calls `shrink()`, that shrinks your snake one by one.

Comment: MADE IT WORK, check it above